# Order pagination result in Symfony 1

Tags: pagination, symfony1

I have a question concerning pagination in Symfony 1. I have the code below which give me the paginated records of the Offer table. How could I change the order from asc to desc?

```
protected function getPager() {
    $pager = new sfDoctrinePager('Offer', 1000);
    $pager->setQuery($this->buildQuery());
    $pager->setPage($this->getPage());
    $pager->init();
    return $pager;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not the pager having to add the order but the query. So you can create a query manually (where you set also the ordering needed) and pass it to `$pager->setQuery()`.

Answer (score 0):

if i may add a solution.

use jQuery + datatables.net.  its neat and fast.  Message me for sample code.
ejaymejr@gmail.com

Preview of the Datatable i created.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YoEL.jpg